# requests works, scrapy.Request does not (why...?)

Tags: python-requests, pagination, scrapy, xmlhttprequest

- I'm attempting to scrape the first 20 pages of https://en.mzadqatar.com/qatar/cars/sale
- The site has an XHR call which checks the origin page of the user before providing the next page.
- If a user enters on page 2 the site will revert the user back to the home page.
- The desired response can replicated by entering at the above link and then clicking the "NEXT" button at the bottom of the page.
  3
- If you enter directly through this link https://en.mzadqatar.com/qatar/cars/sale?page=1 the website will revert back to the home page.

I've managed to successfully move through each page with the following code using requests, however I cannot replicate the same response using scrapy.Request. Where am I going wrong.....?

Here is the successful code using the requests library:

```
import requests

url = "https://en.mzadqatar.com/search"

payload = "type_id=0&id=1&subCategoryId=&pagination=1&search_type=pagination&km_from=&km_to=&price_from=&price_to=&cityId=&CartypeID=&Fueltype=&subsubCategoryId=&gear=&CylinderNumber=&cars_guarantee=&car_condition=&carcolor=&manfactureYear_from=&manfactureYear_to="
headers = {
    "cookie": "laravel_session=QYDOviHE487FjGC2FvIaAPNnNdypE9dQcupLrylL",
    "authority": "en.mzadqatar.com",
    "accept": "*/*",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,lo;q=0.8",
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    "dnt": "1",
    "origin": "https://en.mzadqatar.com",
    "referer": "https://en.mzadqatar.com/qatar/cars/sale",
    "sec-ch-ua": "'Chromium';v='104', ' Not A;Brand';v='99', 'Google Chrome';v='104'",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-ch-ua-platform": "'macOS'",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
    "sec-gpc": "1",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest"
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)

url = "https://en.mzadqatar.com/qatar/cars/sale"

querystring = {"page":"1"}

payload = ""
headers = {
    "cookie": "laravel_session=QYDOviHE487FjGC2FvIaAPNnNdypE9dQcupLrylL",
    "authority": "en.mzadqatar.com",
    "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,lo;q=0.8",
    "dnt": "1",
    "referer": "https://en.mzadqatar.com/qatar/cars/sale",
    "sec-ch-ua": "'Chromium';v='104', ' Not A;Brand';v='99', 'Google Chrome';v='104'",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-ch-ua-platform": "'macOS'",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
    "sec-gpc": "1",
    "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```

Here is the code using scrapy.Requests that reverts back to the homepage

```
import scrapy

class MzSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'mz'
    allowed_domains = ['mzadqatar.com']
    start_urls = ['https://en.mzadqatar.com/qatar/cars/sale']

    search_url = "https://en.mzadqatar.com/search"

    search_body = "type_id=0&id=1&subCategoryId=&pagination=2&search_type=pagination&km_from=&km_to=&price_from=&price_to=&cityId=&CartypeID=&Fueltype=&subsubCategoryId=&gear=&CylinderNumber=&cars_guarantee=&car_condition=&carcolor=&manfactureYear_from=&manfactureYear_to="

    dict_search_body = {
        "type_id": 0,
        "id": 1,
        "subCategoryId":"",  
        "pagination": 1,
        "search_type": "pagination",
        "km_from": "",
        "km_to": "",
        "undefined":"" ,
        "cityId": "",
        "CartypeID":"" ,
        "Fueltype": "",
        "subsubCategoryId": "",
        "gear": "",
        "CylinderNumber": "",
        "cars_guarantee":"", 
        "car_condition": "",
        "carcolor": "",
        "manfactureYear_from":"", 
        "manfactureYear_to": ""
    }

    search_headers = {
       
        "authority": "en.mzadqatar.com",
        "accept": "*/*",
        "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,lo;q=0.8",
        "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        "dnt": "1",
        "origin": "https://en.mzadqatar.com",
        "referer": "https://en.mzadqatar.com/qatar/cars/sale",
        "sec-ch-ua": "'Chromium';v='104', ' Not A;Brand';v='99', 'Google Chrome';v='104'",
        "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
        "sec-ch-ua-platform": "'macOS'",
        "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
        "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
        "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
        "sec-gpc": "1",
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
        "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest"
    }

    url = "https://en.mzadqatar.com/qatar/cars/sale?page=1"
    
    headers = {
    
        "authority": "en.mzadqatar.com",
        "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
        "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,lo;q=0.8",
        "dnt": "1",
        "referer": "https://en.mzadqatar.com/qatar/cars/sale",
        "sec-ch-ua": "'Chromium';v='104', ' Not A;Brand';v='99', 'Google Chrome';v='104'",
        "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
        "sec-ch-ua-platform": "'macOS'",
        "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
        "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
        "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
        "sec-gpc": "1",
        "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
    }

    cookie = {'laravel_session' : 'QYDOviHE487FjGC2FvIaAPNnNdypE9dQcupLrylL'}
     
    def search_requests(self):

        yield scrapy.Request(
            url=self.search_url,
            method='POST',
            headers=self.search_headers,
            body=self.search_body,
            cookies=self.cookie,
            callback=self.start_requests
        )
       
    def start_requests(self):

        yield scrapy.Request(
            url=self.url,
            method='GET',
            headers=self.headers,
            body="",
            cookies=self.cookie,
            callback=self.parse
        )
        
    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.text)
        pass
```

Any help on how to translate requests into scrapy.Requests would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you see you can't get DIFFERENT page results at the same time using SAME cookies. That's why you need to use DIFFERENT cookies for DIFFERENT pages (I use `meta={'cookiejar': ...}` for that):

```
import scrapy


class MzSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'mz'
    allowed_domains = ['mzadqatar.com']
       
    def start_requests(self):
        for page_number in range(1, 10):
            payload = {
                'type_id': '0',
                'id': '1',
                'subCategoryId': '',
                'pagination': str(page_number),
                'search_type': 'pagination',
                'km_from': '',
                'km_to': '',
                'price_from': '',
                'price_to': '',
                'cityId': '',
                'CartypeID': '',
                'Fueltype': '',
                'subsubCategoryId': '',
                'gear': '',
                'CylinderNumber': '',
                'cars_guarantee': '',
                'car_condition': '',
                'carcolor': '',
                'manfactureYear_from': '',
                'manfactureYear_to': '',
            }

            yield scrapy.FormRequest(
                url='https://en.mzadqatar.com/search',
                method='POST',
                formdata=payload,
                headers={
                    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                },
                cb_kwargs={
                    'page_number': page_number,
                },
                meta={'cookiejar': page_number},
                callback=self.get_pagination,
            )
        
    def get_pagination(self, response, page_number):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url=f'https://en.mzadqatar.com/search?page={page_number}',
            meta={'cookiejar': page_number},
            callback=self.parse_pagination,
            cb_kwargs={
                'page_number': page_number,
            }
        )

    def parse_pagination(self, response, page_number):
        with open(f'Page_{page_number}.html', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        pass
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate the answer you gave. I'm embarrassed to say that I've been staring at this for over 12 hours. I still don't fully understand why the Python requests code works with the same cookies for POST request to /search and the GET request for the page...?
Anyway thanks again!!

Comment: Your Scrpy code executes `start_requests` first (`GET` request) and next execute `parse` callback. Your `search_requests` **never executed**.